# Reloading Model After Transition to Route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using Ember 2.x with a route that looks like:

```
  model: function(params) {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      experiment: Ember.$.getJSON(config.apiServer + params.exp)
    });
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    model.reload();
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
```

Looking at http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/reloading-model-when-using-transitiontoroute-approach/2614.

I tried adding `setupController` and an `afterModel` function like that above. However, when I inspect the `model` argument passed in the debugger, it does not have a `model.reload()` method (`model.reload` is `undefined`). How do I force my model to reload if this is the case?

Comment: `model.reload()` is from Ember Data. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_reload

Comment: ah, is there a way to force a reload if I am not using Ember Data?

Comment: Extract the JSON call into a function and call it again. That `setupController` is highly suspicious though.

Comment: Indeed, `setupController` should not do any loading of data. Its role is just to push already-loaded data to the controller (by default it pushes the model).

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone :) Where might be a better section to delegate this logic if not in the `setupController`?

Answer (score -1):

router has reload function so you do `this.refresh()` inside router which re-fetches model